# Connect Spring with MySql in Docker container

Tags: mysql, spring, docker

When i follow this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/#initial and spin up some new docker containers:

```
version: '2'

services:
    db:
      image: mysql
      environment:
                - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
                - MYSQL_USER=test
                - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
                - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      volumes:
            - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
      ports:
            - "3306:3306"
    phpmyadmin:
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
     environment:
            PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
            MYSQL_USER: test
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
     ports:
            - "80:80"
     links:
            # for mysql container
            - "db:db"
volumes:
    db:
        driver: "local"
```

Im not able to connect with the MySql database, when i run the example application in Spring i get the error:

```
Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

My application properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

What goes wrong? I tried also different combinations like localhost. I can reach phpmyadmin in my browser.

Comment: The `db` hostname in `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/test` is a hostname only known to other containers in the docker network you're running. You said you've tried this, but it should be `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test`. Have you tried `curl localhost:3306` from your host with the db container running?

Comment: Hmm i get this one message back from the curl: `}}wpgmysql_native_password?Got packets out of order`

Comment: Don't give `links` parameter in double quotes `""`. I mean try with db:db .

Comment: And also check that 3306 port is not allocated by your local machine . you have to stop the Mysql Server before running docker-compose.yml